# Unicode in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, wxwidgets

I'm creating a calculator application in C++ wxWidgets using Visual Studio 2019. I have created a custom button class that I want to use for all mathematical operations and symbols.

[image: My custom button class]

How can I set the button's label to √ instead of sqrt? If I do that, a ? symbol is displayed instead. I also need to display these symbols on a wxTextCtrl, if I do it I get the following error when I try to compile: (ignore App.razor, the picture is not mine)

[image: Error]

Do I need to change che current character set from ASCII to Unicode? How do you do that?

Comment: It is just a font problem. You should use a font which support such characters.

Comment: I've updated the font from Lato to Arial, which, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font), is a font with Unicode support, and I get the same error message.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it's not a font problem. If the OP uses `"√"` in the source code file then obviously the file must be saved as Unicode, otherwise how can the √ character be retained? That's exactly what the error message is about

Comment: @phuclv, and iKebab897: no, having unicode support is different to have a font which it is able to display such unicode characters. No font can display all assigned unicode characters. Also Google with NOTO fonts (to display all Unicode characters) split the characters in a numerous fonts. And: encoding of source has nothing to do with display encoding (in past this problem was more common, before unicode)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I know no font supports all Unicode characters. But the issue here is that the OP is typing a non-ASCII character into the source code and **VS is asking to save the file in UTF-8** to preserve that character or discard all non-ASCII characters and save the file as ASCII like before

Comment: In any case, the visual studio error is at source level, and it say the encoding of file is supposed not to be unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single character, you can just use wxUniChar.  You create a wxUniChar with a value in hexadecimal of the Unicode code point for the desired character.  Since the Unicode code point of the square root character is U+221A, you can create a wxUniChar for this character like so:

```
wxUniChar c(0x221A);
```

wxUnichar is implicitly convertible to wxString, so (assuming wxWidgets was built in Unicode mode), you can use wxUniChar variables exactly as you would use a wxString.  For example you could do something like:

```
control->SetLabel(c);
```

or

```
dc.DrawText(c,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @New-Pagodi (sorry, don't know how to tag people with spaces in their names) works, but just saving your file in UTF-8 encoding, as MSVS proposes you to do is a much nicer solution. Even in this case notice that you still need to either use `wxString::FromUTF8("√")` or explicitly set your locale encoding to UTF-8 by using `setlocale()`, which is (finally) supported by the recent Windows versions, in which case you can use just `"√", or use wide strings, i.e.` L"√"`.

I.e. you must *both* have the correct bytes (`e2 88 9a` for UTF-8-encoded representation of U+221A) in the file *and* use the correct encoding when creating `wxString` from it if you're using `char*` strings. By default this encoding is *not* UTF-8 under Windows, so using just `wxString("√")` doesn't work.

Comment: you just delete the space and make it one word.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry, what am I supposed to do to have Unicode characters available in my solution, in layman's terms? I'm not familiar with how encodings and locales work.

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to store these special characters inside of an array? I have like:        int ops[10] = { '+', '-', '*', '/', '^' };   Which type should I use to also store characters such as √ and other mathematical symbols?

Comment: I think you need to understand what you're doing and it's really not that complicated: every `char*` string must be associated with some encoding to convert it to/from Unicode correctly. This encoding should, almost always, be UTF-8 nowadays. As for individual "characters", you may use `wchar_t` if you don't care about surrogates (emojis...), or `char32_t` in recent C++ versions or `wxUniChar` for them.